# Is it possible to use MailChimp API to send weekly personal report email to my customers' application?

Tags: api, email, mailchimp

Maybe a silly question, I just hope not...

I have a SaaS application and the next feature is to send every week (if the client ticks the box) a report.

Actually, I do that with my mail server. I retrieve the data from the DB and for each client, I generate an email and I send the email. The emails are different for each client.

I just want to know if it's possible to do that with MailChimp API.

Thanks
Bastien

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer my questions after an answer of the MailChimp's team.

So using MailChimp is not the way to do what I want. But they propose the Mandrill service which is exactly for this kind of stuff, transactionnal email.

There are a lot of specific services for that like sendgrid or mailjet too.

Bastien